# Why doesn't bc show the scale for the result of this expression?

Tags: bash, unix, posix, bc

This expression, I think, should return `0.000`, not `0`.

```
echo "scale = 3 ; 0 / 2" | bc
```

Using `echo "scale = 3 ; scale(0 / 2)" | bc` outputs `3`, so it's obvious that the scale is *applies*, but it's not displaying the output properly.

**What's going on?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dividing 0 by something, the scale won't be considered as it is sure there will never be any decimal values.

You're right, your scale applies, for example try with echo "scale = 3; 1/2" | bc and the output will be .500

Also, if you use a scale only to avoid truncating, you can use the -l options which will allow 20 decimal digits.

This also prove that when dividing 0 by something, the decimal are ignored as when you type :

```
echo "0/2" | bc - l
```

the output will be 0

```
echo "1/2" | bc - l
```

the output will be .50000000000000000000

I hope I made it a little more clear.

Comment: It definitely makes sense though I was hoping for consistent formatting.